# Графический векторный редактор

Tags: c++, алгоритм, graphics

**Графический векторный редактор**.
Для реализации графики желательно использовать graphics.h и еще если понадобиться windows.h.
В процессе написания возникли проблемы с некоторыми вещами:
1) Как реализовать редактируемые геометрические примитивы ( ломаная, прямоугольник, окружность, эллипс, отрезок, многоугольник, хотя бы просто понять как это реализовывается).
2) Как сделать кнопки открытия изображения и его сохранения.
3) Как сделать кнопки undo/redo.
4) В моем текущем коде рабочая область представляет собой фиксированную область внутри окна программы, то есть это просто залитый ( изначально белым цветом ) прямоугольник внутри окна.
Есть ли какие-нибудь книги которые смогут как-то направить меня или же помогут в написании подобного или посоветуйте что-нибудь если вы с чем-нибудь подобным сталкивались или просто готовы помочь. Буду благодарен каждому совету. Спасибо!

[Ссылка на Google Drive архив с проектом](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ifniiqgCM1ZzdQ7_t9_7E39Kl2awSGZb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Используйте Direct2D.

Comment: Постарайтесь задать узкий, конкретный вопрос и расписать его как можно подробнее. Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном. Почитайте статью «[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)» в справке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если не устраивает функция line, используйте [Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0). Перечисленное далее всё строится из линий, например точки окружности, очевидно так: [image: ф-ла]
2. Для начала определитесь со структурой данных (это пункт 0), если по условию задачи вам не нужно генерировать настоящий векторный формат - сохраняйте любым, удобным для восстановления образом, в простой текстовый файл. Иначе - см. [например тут](ftp://ftp.cs.uregina.ca/pub/class/115/SVG/fonggensvg.html)
3. Есть несколько вариантов, самая очевидная идея - иметь массив (стек) `history`, и делать `push` сгенерированного вектора в этот массив при каждом действии. Кнопка "UNDO", соответственно, делает `pop`, ложит полученное в стек `redoHistory`, отображает на экран последний вектор из оставшегося в стеке. Кнопка "REDO" делает то же самое  со стеком `redoHistory`. При любом другом действии `redoHistory` очищается. Другой вариант - правильный, древовидный и рекурсивный, но например в Windows, функция Undo так обычно не умеет.
4. Всё ок. Но если надо сильно по красоте и простоте, возьмите [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) или [Allegro](http://liballeg.org/)
5. гугл покажет массу книг на тему графики на C++, но вы можете [просто](https://github.com/acmyu/SimpleVectorEditor) [читать](https://github.com/dzuongld/MyDraw) [исходники](https://github.com/alexaquino/uDraw) и [статьи с кодом](http://www.ucancode.net/SVG_VECTOR_GRAPHICS_EDITOR_Source_Code.htm)

Comment: Спасибо большой, очень информативно, а главное полезно)

Comment: Здравствуйте, можете пожалуйста подсказать как сделать открывающееся диалоговое окно для выбора текстового файла который будет являться файловым потоком ввода, я уже сделал сохранение через текстовый документ. Заранее спасибо!